# How to get ALL forest nodes arranged from left to right without overlapping bands?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I want to get all nodes to be in ascending order from left to right. If I use `fit=band` the 2 subtrees left and right are in good order without any overlaps. But the left subtree is far too right and the nodes 9,11,12 are right from node 13. I don't want a special solution for this tree but a solution for trees in common.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\makeatletter\tikzset{use path/.code={\tikz@addmode{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath#1} \appto\tikz@preactions{\let\tikz@actions@path#1}}}\makeatother
\forestset{show boundary/.style={
before drawing tree={get min s tree boundary=\minboundary, get max s tree boundary=\maxboundary}, tikz+={\draw[red,use path=\minboundary]; \draw[red,use path=\maxboundary];}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
    for tree={l sep=1em, s sep=0.6em, anchor=center, 
        inner sep=0.3em, fill=red!50,fit=band,
        circle,minimum size=20pt, font=\sffamily
    },
  [13
    [4,show boundary
        [2]
        [5
                [,phantom]
            [7
                [,phantom]
                [9
                    [,phantom]
                    [11
                        [,phantom]
                        [12]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [19]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[[image: Not in order1]

Comment: I could tweak this special tree with a `where level=0{s sep=5cm}{}` to look right, but for that you have to tweak every special tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A phantom child of 13 between 4 and 19, with `fit=band` and vertically aligned to the parent 13 (`calign with current`), should do the trick.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\makeatletter\tikzset{use path/.code={\tikz@addmode{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath#1} \appto\tikz@preactions{\let\tikz@actions@path#1}}}\makeatother
\forestset{show boundary/.style={
before drawing tree={get min s tree boundary=\minboundary, get max s tree boundary=\maxboundary}, tikz+={\draw[red,use path=\minboundary]; \draw[red,use path=\maxboundary];}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
    for tree={l sep=1em, s sep=0.6em, anchor=center, 
        inner sep=0.3em, fill=red!50,fit=band,
        circle,minimum size=20pt, font=\sffamily
    },
  [13
    [4,show boundary
        [2]
        [5
                [,phantom]
            [7
                [,phantom]
                [9
                    [,phantom]
                    [11
                        [,phantom]
                        [12]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
      ]
    [,phantom,calign with current]
    [19]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT: For easier input.** It is possible to automatically phantomize the empty nodes, as shown below. Note that (i) `where content={}{phantom}{}` occurs within `delay`, as the content option is not "filled" when the tree preamble is processed; and that (ii) `where content` occurs *outside* `for tree` to avoid a double loop.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\makeatletter\tikzset{use path/.code={\tikz@addmode{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath#1} \appto\tikz@preactions{\let\tikz@actions@path#1}}}\makeatother
\forestset{show boundary/.style={
before drawing tree={get min s tree boundary=\minboundary, get max s tree boundary=\maxboundary}, tikz+={\draw[red,use path=\minboundary]; \draw[red,use path=\maxboundary];}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
  for tree={l sep=1em, s sep=0.6em, anchor=center, 
    inner sep=0.3em, fill=red!50,fit=band,
    circle,minimum size=20pt, font=\sffamily
  },
  delay={where content={}{phantom}{}},
  [13
    [4,show boundary
      [2]
      [5
        []
        [7
          []
          [9
            []
            [11
              []
              [12]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [,calign with current]
    [19]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2: A general and automatic solution.**  The idea is to automatically insert a `fit=band,calign with current` node between each pair of siblings. These nodes will then function as "separators" between the two sibling subtrees. The other nodes do *not* need `fit=band`. (Compared to the previous solutions, this deals correctly with binary branches inside unary branches; see node "X" below. Remove the "X" from the code to arrive at the original tree.)

This is in fact all we need to do to solve the linearization problem, all the other options are there for prettier input; in particular `coordinate,phantom` makes all empty nodes small and invisible. I also put the code in the style, so that it's easy to use in multiple trees.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  bst/.style={
    delay={
      where content={}{
        coordinate,phantom
      }{
        s sep=0.6em, anchor=center, 
        inner sep=0.3em, fill=red!50,
        circle, minimum size=20pt, font=\sffamily,
      },
      where n children=2{
        for 1={insert after={[,coordinate,phantom,calign with current,fit=band]}}
      }{},
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} bst
  [13
    [4
      [2]
      [5
        []
        [7
          [X]
          [9
            []
            [11
              []
              [12]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [19]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT 3: Make this work for non-binary branching trees.** Strictly speaking, this is more than the OP wants, but it might be useful for someone. The idea is simply to put separator nodes between each pair of adjacent siblings. This is achieved by `where n children=0{}{for 1={for following siblings={insert before={...}}}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  bst/.style={
    delay={
      where content={}{
        coordinate,phantom
      }{
        s sep=0.6em, anchor=center, 
        inner sep=0.3em, fill=red!50,
        circle, minimum size=20pt, font=\sffamily,
      },
      where n children=0{}{for 1={for following siblings={
            insert before={[,coordinate,phantom,calign with current,fit=band]},
      }}},
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} bst
  [13
    [4
      [2]
      [5
        []
        [7
          [X]
          [Y
            [1]
            [2]
          ]
          [9
            []
            [11
              []
              [12]
            ]
          ]
          [Z
            [4]
            [5
              [8]
              [9]
            ]
            [6]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [19]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yaa this is right  -- I should not have removed all the phantom(s) in my answer

Comment: @jsbibra Note that caligning the parent with the extra phantom node is crucial for this to work.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Thanks! Edit2 is a good solution for me where you only have to use a style and do not have to fiddle with the special tree structure. Particularly if you have to print a lot of random trees...

Answer (score 0):

the solution may not be your liking --i have removed the phantom intermediate nodes and added them at the end

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
    for tree={
         fill=red!50,fit=band,
        circle, font=\sffamily
    },
  [13
    [4
        [2]
        [5
            [7
                [9
                    [11
                        [12]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]                        [,phantom]
    [19]                        [,phantom]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, that’s not what I am looking for. For binary search trees (BST) it’s important to see the direction of the child nodes.